# How to both div tag and its class nestedly using css in Angular?

Tags: css, angular

I have a tag like this in Angular

```
<div [class]="{error: condition}">{{ message }}<div>
```

how to nest div tag and it class "error" nestedly in CSS? i.e. how to have .error selector inside div selector in css file?

Note: Error class should include div properties also.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the descendant selector, which is represented by a space ( ) between selectors.

```
div.error {
  /* CSS properties for the div element with class "error" */
}

div.error div {
  /* CSS properties for nested div elements inside the div with class "error" */
}
```